# Why does AppCompatActivity not throw RuntimeException("Stub!") where as Activity does?

Tags: android, testing, android-activity

I was looking at the decompiled .class files for AppCompatActivity and Activity and noticed that while every method in Activity.class threw a runtime exception

```
throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
```

But the same wasn't true for AppCompatActivity, Is there a reason for the same ?

I know that android.jar only contains stub implementations of android dependencies but isn't the same true for support library classes as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that android.jar only contains stub implementations of android dependencies

That is because the real implementation of the framework classes is part of the firmware. `android.jar` is there merely to make the compiler happy.

> isn't the same true for support library classes as well?

No, because the real implementation of the classes is in the library itself, to be compiled into your app.

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't download the `Sources for Android`, You can find it from `SDK Manager` [image]